# How do I call OnTriggerEnter multiple times in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to push a button (inside a medical patient) multiple times, with OnCollisionEnter(); the problem is that it collides with the patient's mesh and the animations are always triggered, which is not good for me. With OnTriggerEnter(), it works fine as it is a trigger and does not collide with the medical patient's mesh, only with my avatar, which uses hand tracking. I want to call OnTriggerEnter() multiple times. I thought about instantiating the asset again, then destroying the first asset, but I have not gotten any luck. Please help! The following code is attached to my buttons inside the patient, which is to be palpated. How can I trigger OnTriggerEnter multiple times?

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (palpation_patient.animation_selection == 6 && palpation_patient.pain_level == 1)
    {
        palpation_patient.animator.SetLayerWeight(1, 1);
    }
    if (palpation_patient.animation_selection == 6 && palpation_patient.pain_level == 2)
    {
        palpation_patient.animator.SetLayerWeight(2, 1);
    }
    if (palpation_patient.animation_selection == 6 && palpation_patient.pain_level == 3)
    {
        palpation_patient.animator.SetLayerWeight(3, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will [Collider.OnTriggerStay ( ... )](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerStay.html) solves the requirement in your case?

Comment: Yes, it did. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're MOST WELCOME and KEEP SMILING :-)